# Can Resque workers run without a copy of redis running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I start a worker with:

```
rake environment resque:work RAILS_ENV=development VVERBOSE=1 QUEUE=* LOGFILE=/Users/matteo/workspace/APP/log/resque.log --trace
```

I get the output:

```
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
** Invoke resque:setup 
** Execute resque:work
```

A quick ps tells me the process is up and running.

Now I do NOT have an instance of Redis running. A quick `ps auxwwww | grep redis-server` confirms that.

Shouldn't the worker fails?

I downloaded the resque code and put a breakpoint into the resque code in worker.rb:

```
(rdb:1) eval redis
#<Redis::Namespace:0x007f868cb57880 @namespace=:resque, @redis=#<Redis client v2.2.2 connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1 (Redis v0.07)>>
```

How is this possible nothing is running on that port?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers is: "No, workers cannot run without a copy of Redis running".

The problem was caused by the fakeredis gem. Even though the gem was not included in the development environment the developer was requiring "redis/connction/memory" therefore using a fakeredis instance.

Answer (score 1):

Resque definetely requires redis to work, although it may appear that your queue is up, it will fail to process without redis.

You can view the status of your queues by going to this url after booting up your server...

```
http://localhost:3000/resque/overview
```

That is if you have the following in your gemfile

```
gem 'resque', :require => "resque/server"
```

OR if you don't have that setup run this in the console `resque-web` to get the admin interface accessible at `localhost:3000/overview`

If you don't get an error and can access that page without a redis error, redis must be running somewhere, perhaps as a service on bootup?

For basic redis/resque setup see here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast